# How to increase output buffer size in Windows command line window?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, qemu, display-settings

I am working with xv6 in WSL of Windows 10. After running `make && make qemu-nox` and quitting immediately from qemu, I need to check the output of make. But most lines of the output of make were removed; only a few lines at the end of the output burst are kept. I have changed the Buffer Size in "Command Prompt" Properties dialog from 50 to 500 but the same problem persists. Is there any working way to increasing the output buffer of the command window so that I can check the output of `make && make qemu-nox` from very beginning? Or, if the output is indeed removed by qemu or something else, how can I prevent such removal? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Properties* -> *Options* -> *Command History* -> *Buffer Size* is the number of previous commandlines that Windows Console will remember.  To change the scrollback buffer, you want *Properties* -> *Layout* -> *Screen Buffer Size* -> *Height*.

Since this defaults to a pretty large number already (9001 on my system), it's more likely that something in the build is calling the `clear` command (or writing its equivalent escape sequence to the terminal).

As possible workarounds, consider:

#### Using `tmux`

Perhaps this is overkill, but my normal workflow is to use `tmux`.  It's installed by default in some distributions, but easily installable if not.  As far as I can tell, its scrollback buffer is not cleared with the `clear` command (or its equivalent escape sequences).

To run it, and use it's scrollback feature:

- The default scrollback buffer is 2000 lines. To change it, if you really do need more, create `~/.tmux.conf` with the following line:

  ```
  set -g history-limit 10000
  ```
- Run `tmux`
- Run your build
- To enter "copy mode", in which you can scroll back, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (the `tmux` "prefix" chord), then press <kbd>[</kbd> (I hope I have that correct - My settings are slightly different).
- Then <kbd>Pg-Up</kbd> as needed
- <kbd>q</kbd> will exit Copy Mode (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)

#### Pipe to `less`

For a likely faster solution, if you choose not to use `tmux`, `(make && make qemu-nox) | less` should allow you to capture the full build into the scrollable `less` command.

#### Redirect to a file

```
(make && make qemu-nox) &> buildlog.txt
```

The `&>` is needed to redirect stderr to the file as well.

#### Redirect to a file while still displaying the output on screen

```
((make && make qemu-nox) 2>&1) | tee buildlog.txt
```